# Exception message is been displaying in the textbox which is handled in the function should be changed to a simple error message.

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a web application using asp.net with c#,Code used is specified below.

```
public string fnDisplayManualRecords1(string patid)
{
    string cmdString = "select top 1 (patientid) from Patient_Data where PatientID like '"+patid+"%' order by PatientID desc";
    con = new SqlConnection(str);

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdString, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@patid", patid);
        string result = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        log.Debug("Error: Inside catch block of fnCreateManualRecords");
        log.Error("Error msg:" + ex);

        log.Error("Stack trace:" + ex.StackTrace);
        //transaction.Rollback();
        return ex.ToString();
    }

    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }


}
```

This is a function been called as is shown below,its working fine for proper data,But when it catches the exception and it will display the exception message inside the textbox shown below as

`System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   at myConnection.fnDisplayManualRecords1(String patid) in d:\Shreyas\PMS_CMR\pms_production_manual_updation\App_Code\Connection.cs:line 2157`

```
  string result = obj.fnDisplayManualRecords1(patid);
  txtlast.Text = result.ToString();
```

Now I just need to change the exception message as ‘No Data Found’ instead of that actual exception message shown above.

Comment: Try not to throw exception in such a simple situations .
finding no result as a database query is usual problem and could be checked by a "if" statement, without overhead of TRYing to convert it to a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of the *NullReferenceException* is that you *should check* if 
returned value is null. Do not forget to close `SqlConnection` as well
as `SqlCommand`: **using** construction, IMHO, is the best choice.

```
public string fnDisplayManualRecords1(string patid) {
  string cmdString = "select top 1 (patientid) from Patient_Data where PatientID like '"+patid+"%' order by PatientID desc";

  using (new SqlConnection(str)) {
    try {
      con.Open();

      using (cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdString, con)) {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@patid", patid);

        Object data = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        // Check if returned value is null: special case  
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, data))
          return "No data found"; // <- Your message here

        return data.ToString(); 
      }
    }
    catch (DataException ex) { // <- Ordinary data (SQL server) errors
      log.Debug("Error: Inside catch block of fnCreateManualRecords");
      log.Error("Error msg:" + ex);
      log.Error("Stack trace:" + ex.StackTrace);

      return ex.ToString();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
    // Do stuff
}
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    // Log error

    // Return friendly string
    return "No Data Found";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an exception with Custom Message and return it. :)

```
try
{
    con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdString, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@patid", patid);
    string result = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    return result;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

    log.Debug("Error: Inside catch block of fnCreateManualRecords");
    log.Error("Error msg:" + ex);

    log.Error("Stack trace:" + ex.StackTrace);
    //transaction.Rollback();
     //Custom Exception
     Exception sqlException= new Exception("No Data Found");
     return sqlException;
    //return ex.ToString();
}

finally
{
    con.Close();
}
```